# DayOfWeek function dynamically in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a column like this abc - 11/04/2020 1:17:40  date format I want to create a derived column where I need `dayOfWeek` dynamically for every row present in abc column.

I tried using a derived column in adf but it is not showing the day everything is coming as NULL.

Below is the image of the dataflow pipeline where I am trying to add a derive column with the expression. I tried passing the column abc there but no use it is not coming.

How can I solve this issue?

[image: Sample image of table]

Comment: What does the value inside the toDate() function look like? If the conversion is failing I think you would get NULL back. You may need to specify the date format for the conversion to work: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#todate

Comment: I tried adding the column name ie abc inside toDate(), because I want to get the days for all the rows which is present in my source.

Comment: Basically I don't want to add single date data in toDate() function it should dynamically pick up the dates from column name specified in function and give days name in derieved column. Hope I am able to understand my query

Comment: I understand needing it to be dynamic, but what is the format of the date data you are trying to convert? My point is if the conversion is failing you would expect to get NULL.

Comment: Yes Joel I was dong wrong format,Thanks for pointing out ,one more query is there a way to print the dayofweek name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could using bellow expressions, add the date format:

```
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))
```

I tested and it works well:
[image]

Update:

For your another question, we could using `case` to achieve that:

```
case(dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==0,'Sunday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==1,'Monday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==2,'Tuesday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==3,'Wednesday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==4,'Thursday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==5,'Fraiday',
dayOfWeek(toDate(abc,'MM/dd/yyyy'))==6,'Saturday'
 )
```

Scheenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks got it ,I was using wrong format ,one more question is there any way to get the dayOfweek name llike we got 4 so output should comes as "Thursday". I am not sure if that happens but it will be great if it works like that

Comment: @SHIBASHISHTRIPATHY You're welcome. If we want get dayOfWeek() '4' became 'Thursday', with  if or case expression may achieve that. I'm not sure but I will try it.  If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @SHIBASHISHTRIPATHY, I figure it out, please see my update!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? A very simple one. Here you can use the variable 'abc' instead of UTC time.

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dddd')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention!